# Roll back to stable version Lubuntu LXQt

Tags: apt, upgrade, lubuntu, ppa, lxqt

I use this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm-qt
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

to update my LXQt desktop and PCManFM-qt but everything went wrong.
Please help me to get back to the same stable version.

Stable versions:

```
LXQt: 0.14
PCManFM-qt: 0.14
```

Now:

```
LXQt: 0.16
PCManFM-qt: 0.17
```

Comment: `but everything went wrong` -- What went wrong?

Comment: Terminal, Openbox, GUI, etc

Comment: Easiest way to fix would be to perform a fresh install.

Comment: Those repositories are intended for QA-testing specific packages, usually on a testing system (unless you've done your homework on what the effects will be). I said the upgrade required lots of changes that were easiest accomplished via upgrade to a later release.  The fix in my opinion is either restoration of backups, or *install using existing partition*.  (you'll find a *doc* that sorta walks through QA-testing this on Lubuntu's discourse) FYI:  The version you went to **is stable**, just not intended for 20.04 (built so we can *test* specific interactions).

Comment: The warning on that PPA "**⚠️ This PPA is not meant to be used ⚠️**" was there for a reason...  I didn't suggest it intentionally and gave my answer last question.

Comment: FYI:   the discourse thread I referenced in comment is https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743  (search for "*install using existing partition*" which is why I used that *wording* instead of my more common generic *upgrade via re-install*). The purpose of that *doc* is of course QA-testing the current *impish* release, but that testcase has existed since Lubuntu 19.04 on launchpad (in code) as a *manual testcase*

Answer (score 5):

In case your terminal does not work, open a virtual terminal with `ctrl + alt + F3`, and login.

First install ppa-purge, and purge this ppa.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-ci/unstable-ci-proposed
```

This should revert back the packages to the versions available in the repositories.

Just to ensure that all the required packages are there, you can run the following command.

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: not working: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: lxqt-core but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: pcmanfm-qt but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Did you run ppa-purge?

Comment: Yes. i run ppa-purge before.

Comment: Since the OP did a dist-upgrade, ppa-purge probably can't fix it. They will have to go through the apt logs and manually install the correct versions of the packages. Or, restore the clone they took before doing such a drastic update.